# How to use csvsimple

Tags: csvsimple

I want to include a csv file as a table into my overleaf-document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\csvautotabular{population.csv}
```

I have no idea, why it is not working. Does someone know ? ;-)

Comment: First of all look at the MWE in my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578577/231952. Then edit your question, possibly providing a MWE. Your code, as it is, can not work: for example, `\csvautotabular` must be used in the document body not in the preamble

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your response! I do include it in the document body. Do I have to do overwrite the file as you did? (That would be a huge amount of characters)
```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.csv}
game id,start,dimensions,number of players,error type,survived rounds,avg iter dur,max iter dur
1,,{(46, 58)},6,--,3,0.0189638150252525,0.070585
1,,{(46, 58)},6,--,3,0.0189638150252525,0.070585
...
6,,{(42, 71)},5,--,63,0.006719767371205704,1.936
\end{filecontents*}
```

Comment: You do not need `filecontents` in the real life. It's mostly useful for producing minimal working examples.

Comment: Well, then I still don't know my mistake. I did everything exactly like you suggested :( Do you know another package which I could try?

Comment: in order to help you, you should open a new question, provide a MWE and explain the details of your problem in more depth. If the code of my answer below doesn't work, it's probably an Overleaf issue.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have this external `test.csv` file:

```
Lorem,Ipsum,Dolor,Sit,Amet
one,one,one,one,one
two,two,two,two,two
three,three,three,three,three
one,one,one,one,one
two,two,two,two,two
three,three,three,three,three
```

Then the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
 
 \csvautotabular{test.csv}

\end{document}
```

will produce this:

[image]